# how can I upload and download files in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and i am making an application which will upload a file(text), and then after some processing on the file, i want to download it and delete the original file. Also specify if there is some online source on this.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: simple upload and download of file.

Comment: The tutorials and sample code for Rails, and for basic Web theory, will cover these things. Get reading and experimenting. Your question is too broad for us to answer concisely within the scope of this forum

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file input just like any other rails form input.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files